# Gnome-terminal: reset keyboard shortcut

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, gnome-terminal

I would like to reset the keyboard shortcuts of `gnome-terminal`.

I tried:

- `apt-get autoremove gnome-terminal`
- `apt-get purge gnome-terminal`

and these successfully installed, but made no difference.

Thanks!

Comment: To reset or modify individual hotkey keyboard shortcuts, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/17626/how-can-i-restore-default-keyboard-shortcuts/240103#240103

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found.

```
cd ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/
rm -r keybindings/
```

Thank you anyway

Comment: In my environment (Fedora 18), I also need to re-login. After your commands, just restarting gnome-terminal is not work but it worked after I close and open X-session.

Comment: In newer versions of Ubuntu (15.04) its: ```dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can try use `reset` or `tput reset`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean reset the shortcut key for opening the Terminal window?
If yes, you can find it on Keyboard section of the System Settings. What GNU/Linux distribution are you using ? On Ubuntu you go to System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Launchers and there you find Launch Terminal. Default shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: No, it's the shortcut which for example open a new tab in terminal.

Comment: for this there is the "Keyboard Shortcuts..." section on the "Edit" menu. Default keyboard shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+T